# Ctrl+s does not always save a file on IDLE

Tags: python-idle

Sometimes I can save a script by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> when using IDLE, but then other times it fails to save for no reason, as haven't changed anything. Is this a bug of some kind? It's starting to irritate me.

Platform: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Im not using the command prompt!

Comment: You'll have to tell us what program you're running - Python is a programming language, not a text editor.

Comment: Im using the IDLE in Python 2.7

Comment: Do you have more that one window open in IDLE, e.g. an IDLE shell window and an IDLE edit window?

Comment: Just the edit window Ned...

Comment: Yes i _do_ understand that Python is a programming language! Thank you Keyser and Yann. Im running windows 7 professional if that's any use.

Comment: I think your question is (correct me if I'm wrong): _"Ctrl-s not always saving in Python IDLE on Windows"_. Or something like that. I think the confusion comes from IDLE being somewhat official, though no professional uses it (I think). You should edit the question.

Comment: Correct keyser, can you answer that one?

Comment: I sadly can't. I hope the right people will see it with the idle tag.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue12387) is related, even though it's Python 3. It says that there are bugs when caps lock is enabled.

Comment: That solves it Keyser, it's the Caps Lock. That's maddening. Ok, thanks very much for your time, all the best.

Comment: On June 16, 2014, I committed a patch that should have fixed the Caps Lock issue at least on Windows. https://bugs.python.org/issue12387#msg220331.  If it fails, I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

It may be some character. I faced that same trouble, then I removed some character, such as "Ç" and it worked fine.

Comment: Where is this special character? In your code? How come?

Comment: Were you using 2.x?  Saving unicode chars in the Basic Multilingual Plane should not be an issue with 3.x unless you specify an encoding other than utf-8 in a coding comment in the file and then add characters not supported by that encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that use of character æ, ø, å, even as it is comment out, Python 2.7 IDE won't save the file.